# Tikz mindmap example from manual gives error

Tags: tikz-pgf, mindmaps

Looking to produce a tikz mindmap which gives the error missing number treated as zero l.9 . Can anyone tell me what the problem is?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}

\begin{document} 

\tikz [mindmap, every node/.style=concept, concept color=black!20, grow=cyclic,
    level 1/.append style={level distance=4.5cm,sibling angle=90},
    level 2/.append style={level distance=3.5cm, sibling angle=45}] 
  \node [root concept] {Computational Complexity} %  root
    child { node {Computational Problems}
      child { node {Problem Measures} }
      child { node {Problem Aspects} }
      child { node {Problem Domains} }
      child { node {Key Problems} }
    }
    child { node {Computational Models}
      child { node {Turing Machines} }
      child { node {Random-Access Machines} }
      child { node {Circuits} }
      child { node {Binary Decision Diagrams} }
      child { node {Oracle Machines} }
      child { node {Programming in Logic} }
    }
    child { node {Measuring Complexity}
      child { node {Complexity Measures} }
      child { node {Classifying Complexity} }
      child { node {Comparing Complexity} }
      child { node {Describing Complexity} }
    }
    child { node {Solving Problems}
      child { node {Exact Algorithms} }
      child { node {Randomization} }
      child { node {Fixed-Parameter Algorithms} }
      child { node {Parallel Computation} }
      child { node {Partial Solutions} }
      child { node {Approximation} }
};
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replacing `grow=cyclic` with `grow cyclic` yields:

[image]

Comment: Sooo simple … don’t tell David! ;-)

Comment: @Speravir: Only simple once solve it, took me a while to track it down as I was sure it wast the usual missing `tikz` library, and the error message seemed to imply that something was missing units.. Plus David will probably never look at this question -- it is `tikz`. :-)

Comment: Yes, I can imagine. It should be a joke. :-)